# Why is lead soft?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, physical-chemistry, crystals, metals

As most of us know, lead, at room temperature, is quite soft. You can easily bend a lead rod. You can easily scrape a small piece off it with your nail, and you can even pull a thin long piece apart. This can't easily be done with iron. In both cases, a metallic bonding holds the atoms in place. Is lead soft because the metallic bonding in lead is weaker (which I can't imagine because metallic bindings are the same for every metal, I assume)? Sodium is soft too at room temperature, while mercury is even fluid. Does this mean that the metallic bindings in mercury and sodium are weaker too (than in hard metals)? Solid mercury is soft too. So what makes lead soft?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Broadly, lead isn't very well bonded (we know this because of its relatively low melting temperature of 327°C), and its bonding in the solid state is face-centered cubic (FCC), which offers a large number of slip systems—12—with close spacing. (Notably ductile gold and copper, for example, are also FCC metals).

[image]

Consequently, dislocations move easily through lead, resulting in a low yield stress.

Comment: Chemomechanics! this is a most excellent answer! -Niels